# django_filters need apply only for list action

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filters

I have a simple filter:

```
class ContentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    app = filters.UUIDFilter(required=True)
    ...
```

I used it on simple ModelViewSet

```
class ContentView(ModelViewSet):
    """View for Content"""
    serializer_class = ContentSerializer
    filterset_class = ContentFilter
```

But when I try get /contents/:id/ I get error:

```
{
  "app": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}
```

So, my question. How can I set `required=True` only for my `list` action?

My solution is:

```
 def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        """We need display filter only on list request, otherwise we get error on /id/ requests about app is required"""
        if self.action != 'list':
            self.filterset_class = None
        return super().filter_queryset(queryset)
```

What is the better solution, maybe I can configure it inside filter class?

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Yes I add it in question:

My solution is ...

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't come up more, `required=True` should obviously not be applied for any detail endpoint. It's basically a bug. Anyway I used your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but maybe someone would like to do it in a different way. I came up with overriding the filterset_class as a property and choosing if I want to use a filterset_class or not based on the action. I did this for single-responsibility in my code (filter_queryset should filter, not pick a filterset_class).

my code:

```
from typing import Type
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from rest_framework.mixins import ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from .filters import FooFilter


class FooViewSet(RetrieveModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

    @property
    def filterset_class(self) -> Type[filters.FilterSet] | None:
        if self.action == 'list':
            return FooFilter
```